# log4net with .NET Framework 4.6.2

Tags: asp.net, .net, log4net

I got my new Windows 10 having to install Visual Studio 2019 only with .NET Framework 4.6.2. I also all frameworks available available in the VS Installer including the framework 4.5.2, but cannot select it, so i have chosen 4.6.2 using my latest log4net package. But now it stopped creating my log file when using the application.

Looking at the "Supported Frameworks" page at Apache Log4Net it does not list 4.6 or 4.6.2. Does that mean its not supporting at all. Tried to clone the github repo compiling on my own but still, it is not creating my log file.

Any known issues with .NET 4.6.x?

Update with code:
Globals.asax.cs contains this:

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
    }
```

web.config contains this:

```
  <configSections>
   <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>
```

and this:

```
 <log4net>
   <root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="file"/>
  </root>
  <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
   <encoding value="utf-8"/>
   <file value="log\LOG_"/>
   <appendToFile value="true"/>
   <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
   <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
   <maximumFileSize value="15MB"/>
   <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
   <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd'.log'"/>
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline"/>
   </layout>
 </appender>
</log4net>
```

and my cs files call this to log:

```
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID).Debug(message);
```

Comment: No issues and 4.6 isn't exactly new. There are a ton of blog posts and articles that show how to use log4net. You didn't post any code, so it's impossible to say what's wrong - are you using a config file? Code config? Is the config file missing perhaps?

Comment: Besides, you probably aren't using 4.6 at all - the 4.x versions are binary replacements, which means any new version deployed through a Visual Studio installation or Windows Update replaces the existing one. Even when you thought you were targetting 4.5, you were probably running on a newer runtime

Comment: Have you given the application pool identity write permission to create the log folder and files? If not, how come it can write logs to disk.

Comment: @LexLi it is the default user when you create a pool. But looking at the properties dialog on the log folder I cannot give any permissions to that user. How to do that? Even searching for it doesn’t give me any results on the object explorer.

Comment: @LexLi ok i added the DefaultAppPool to permissions list with full access, still no file being created in the log folder. Just checked another server with another application also running on log4net with .net 4.6.2 and the file is being created there. exact same log4net config and same permissions, can this be some windows specific issue besides security tab settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange. The Global.asax file was missing in the root directory. Since the Global.asax.cs is compiled into the DLL, i thought it runs anyway, but we need to keep Global.asax whose content simply is THIS:

```
﻿<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MyNamespace.App.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

Without this, all the Application_Start having the .Configure() call for log4net is NOT called. Didn't know that.